# gfortran include path with space

Tags: compiler-construction, include, gfortran

I have a space in my directory, and when I try to use the -Idir compiler option, it doesn't recognize the path (because of the space). Is there any way around this? Or should I just rename my path?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way around this?

Did you quote the path with space? You must: `"-Idir with space"` (single or double quotes are *required* here).

> Or should I just rename my path?

Avoiding paths with spaces may be the best solution.

Comment: The quotes do work, but the format seems to be -I"dir_with_spaces"